# Sidekiq: Is it possible to "pause" a queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

Is it possible to "pause" a sidekiq queue?

I have a download job running, but I have to travel/hibernate my Mac
so I want to tell sidekiq to pause for a bit.

Is there a straightforward way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just gracefully shut sidekiq down by sending a `USR1` signal - upon receiving it, it will stop taking new jobs from redis, but complete already running ones

See more [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Signals)

But if your task is long-runing and not split into parts or idempodent then you're out of luck

Answer (score 2):

You cannot stop a job mid-process. If you want to stop processing new jobs from a queue, that's a Sidekiq Pro feature.