# Interactive countdowns in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous

I'm working on a Rails app that needs to have some independent countdowns (user sets via UI the number of minutes before pressing start). Moreover, users may suspend and resume the countdown.

Any suggestions how I can achieve so?

Thanks

Comment: Your countdown must resume after page reload?

Comment: No, the countdown must be independent from the UI, I mean users can stop/resume it but once it starts the user can also close the browser and the countdowns must continue. Once it goes off I will notify subscribers with ActionCable.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make it via background job. For example, with `Sidekiq` ([link](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)). Use `sidekiq-status` ([link](https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status)) gem to sync countdown value with UI. Sidekiq has `pause!` and `unpause!` methods for suspend and resume your countdown.

Create model `countdown`, that belongs to user and has `after_create` callback. Write simple `REST api` for it.

When user starts countdown, UI via AJAX sends the `POST` to `create` action. `Countdown after_create` callback method creates new `Sidekiq` job and saves job_id to self `job_id` property. Your app can access to this job_id via user's association user.countdown.job_id and request status of it using

```
Sidekiq::Status::status user.countdown.job_id
Sidekiq::Status::at user.countdown.job_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The solution seems interesting but it doesn't really solve my issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34231649/284257